# Find number of cells in a row that share the same value, then store those coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am a beginner and I am building a C# Crozzle game.I am trying to find space in a two dimensional array that could possible store a word. So for example, I have a two dimensional array like this:

```
[ 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ]
[ 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 ]
[ 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 ]
[ 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 ]
[ 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 ]
```

0 represents the cell being empty, and 1 represents that it contains a value. I want to get a collection of coordinates that are free. 
So eventually I want to store the starting and end coordinate, like:
    [0,0] -> [0,4],
    [3,0] -> [3,4],
    [3,0] -> [6,0]

Storing them isn't the issue, the issue is finding these patterns of 0's. Anyone know the best way of working this out?

Thanks!

Comment: I would use List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>.  So you can have a list of x,y pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to scan lines and columns of the 2D array. To show up the idea, I've chosen

```
 Tuple<int, int>
 Tuple<Point, Point>
```

to represent ranges in the 1D and 2D arrays correspondingly. Sure, that `Tuple<Point, Point>` is not a good choice and you, probably, want to change it for some tailored class.

```
private static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> ScanLine<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, T sample, int atLeast) {
  int count = 0;
  int index = -1;

  foreach (var item in source) {
    index += 1;

    if (Object.Equals(item, sample))
      count += 1;
    else {
      if (count >= atLeast)
        yield return new Tuple<int, int>(index - count, index - 1);

      count = 0;
    }
  }

  if (count >= atLeast) 
    yield return new Tuple<int, int>(index - count + 1, index);
}

private static IEnumerable<Tuple<Point, Point>> ScanBoard<T>(T[,] source, T sample, int atLeast) {
  // Lines scan
  for (int i = 0; i < source.GetLength(0); ++i) {
    var line = Enumerable.Range(0, source.GetLength(1)).Select(c => source[i, c]);

    foreach (var item in ScanLine(line, sample, atLeast))
      yield return new Tuple<Point, Point>(new Point(item.Item1, i), new Point(item.Item2, i));
  }
  // Columns scan
  for (int i = 0; i < source.GetLength(1); ++i) {
    var line = Enumerable.Range(0, source.GetLength(0)).Select(r => source[r, i]);

    foreach (var item in ScanLine(line, sample, atLeast))
      yield return new Tuple<Point, Point>(new Point(i, item.Item1), new Point(i, item.Item2));
  }
}
```

Test

```
int[,] board = new int[,] {
  { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
  { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
  { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
  { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
};

// room for 3-letter words
Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, ScanBoard(board, 0, 3)));
```

Returns

```
({X=3,Y=0}, {X=6,Y=0})
({X=0,Y=0}, {X=0,Y=4})
({X=3,Y=0}, {X=3,Y=4})
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you please explain the paramters T sample and atLeast? Not quite understanding their role. Appreciate your help

Comment: @kristian: `atLeast` - the word's length (i.e. return lines which have at least 3 zeroes). `T` - generic. So you can use `board` of `char` or `string`, e.g. `char[,] board  = ...`, `var lines = ScanBoard(board, '?', 3)`

Comment: Hi Dmitry, It seems that I keep getting possible Points that are outside the bounds of the array. Any ideas as to why that could be happening?

Comment: @kristian: Could you, please, provide an (counter-)example? A board for which my routine returns wrong output?